# Исключение java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, android, парсер, исключения

Пробовал раньше спарсить простой заголовок сайта - работало. Сейчас вылетает исключение.

```
10-21 07:01:28.061    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketTimeoutException
10-21 07:01:28.061    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
10-21 07:01:28.065    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
10-21 07:01:28.069    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
10-21 07:01:28.073    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
10-21 07:01:28.073    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
10-21 07:01:28.077    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
10-21 07:01:28.081    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
10-21 07:01:28.081    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:579)
10-21 07:01:28.085    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
10-21 07:01:28.089    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
10-21 07:01:28.089    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
10-21 07:01:28.093    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:516)
10-21 07:01:28.097    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
10-21 07:01:28.097    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
10-21 07:01:28.101    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
10-21 07:01:28.101    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.admin.parserasp.MainActivity$mytask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:84)
10-21 07:01:28.109    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.admin.parserasp.MainActivity$mytask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:77)
10-21 07:01:28.109    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-21 07:01:28.113    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-21 07:01:28.117    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-21 07:01:28.117    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-21 07:01:28.121    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-21 07:01:28.125    1455-1472/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)


class mytask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String raspElement;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Document doc=null;
        try{
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pkgh.edu.ru/obuchenie/shedule-of-classes.html").get();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (doc!=null) {

            raspElement = doc.title();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        textview1.setText(raspElement);
    }

}
```

Comment: урл? код? хоть что нибудь? Или вы просто пожаловаться решили?

Comment: @metalurgus написал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL `http://pkgh.edu.ru/obuchenie/shedule-of-classes.html`долго загружается, в среднем 5000 ms. Стандартного таймаута нехватает. Увеличте таймаут:

```
Jsoup.connect("http://pkgh.edu.ru/obuchenie/shedule-of-classes.html").timeout(10*1000).get();
```